# Windows 7 - 64bit OS - Opens java.exe always in a separate command prompt

Tags: windows-7, java, 64-bit, command-line

Upgraded my windows 7 from 32 bit to 64 bit. Installed Java 6 (64 bit) and 7 (64 bit) version.

Whenever i execute "java" in a command prompt, it opens a new command prompt and execute it. Even if i give "java -version" within a command prompt it opens new command prompt and runs it.

Later noticed that most of the exe files opens a empty command prompt and runs. The command prompt remains open until I close the exe file.

The same installation works in other windows 7 PCs without opening new command prompt.

Anyone got any idea how to prevent opening new command window automatically?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use a command prompt with admin rights. Open the cmd.exe with "run as administrator" from the context menu that you get with right click on cmd.exe.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it is opening the Java 6 (32-bit version) instead of the Java 7 (64-bit).  What happens if you put in the full path with the command, pointing to the install location for the 64-bit Java 7?  When it does display the version, what version does it show?

Comment: I executed with full path "D:\apps\java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin\java -version". Still it launches in separate window. Both java 6 and 7 are 64 bit version.

Comment: I think that this has to be an issue with the Java console opening.  I assume when you mention "command" that you are running cmd.exe and then typing in the Java command.  When you use Control Panel > Java, is the Java console set to open or hide?